# Remove "Restore contacts" from Google contacts

Tags: google-contacts

Once Contact is removed from my Contact list, how to ensure it is unreconverable? I would like to remove it permanently, without a restore option.

Answer (score 3):

> 30 days after you delete a contact, it will be removed permanently.

[Source](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=14001).